# How to trigger re-render with `setValue` using react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, react-hook-form

I have a simple form with a select field, it's [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for validation and everything. There's a `Controller` which renders a Material UI `Select`. I would like to set the value of such select using [setValue](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue) from outside the component (in the root of the form, where all controls reside).
This is the piece of code I'm using (slightly simplified not to waste too much of your time)

```
type Props = {
  name: string;
  control: Control<any>;
  options: SelectOptions[];
};
const Select: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  name,
  control,
  options,
}) => (
  <Controller
    control={control}
    name={name}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
      return (
        <FormControl>
          <MuiSelect onChange={onChange}>
            {options.map((o) => (
              <MuiSelectItem key={o.key} value={o.value}>{o.label}</MuiSelectItem>
            ))}
          </MuiSelect>
        </FormControl>
      )
    }}
  />
);
```

As far as changing the value of the select, `setValue` works magically. When I feed a new value, it works as intended. The problem (I guess) is the component is not re-rendered, so the old value is still shown. I'm not sure how to fix this thing and docs did not help a lot. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can use react-hook such as useState() and useEffect() in order to re-render whenever specific value is changed.

Comment: @DevProgrammer I'm not sure how to do that, as I would think there's already a hook used inside Material UI's component.

Comment: For example. 
const { value, setValue } = useState("");

useEffect( () => {
    // write your code here
}, value);

If value is set by setValue, it will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just forgot to set the `value` prop of `<Controller />` to your `<MuiSelect />`. You also have to set a `defaultValue` for your `<Controller />` field, either via the `defaultValue` prop or via `useForm`.

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name={name}
  defaultValue=""
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
    return (
      <FormControl>
        <MuiSelect onChange={onChange} value={value}>
          {options.map((o) => (
            <MuiSelectItem key={o.key} value={o.value}>{o.label}</MuiSelectItem>
          ))}
        </MuiSelect>
      </FormControl>
    )
  }}
/>
```

[image: Edit BasicSelect Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Tried to do so, but it doesn't solve the problem. Perhaps I'm missing something else.

Comment: Did you set a default value for your `<Controller />`? I updated my answer and added a sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the sandbox! There's probably something else interfering in my code. Strange, I was testing this component on an empty page.

Comment: Can you update your question with the whole code?

Comment: I take back what I said, it works like a charm when passing the default value, made a silly mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

As @knoefel said I tried setting the `defaultValue=""` but doesn't work for me(maybe because I am using `FormProvider`). So what I did is use `watch` instead of `value`

```
<Controller
  name='name'
  control={control}
  render={({ field: { onChange } }) => (
    <Select
      dropdownValues={dropdownValues}
      value={watch('name')}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, thanks for sharing.

Comment: watch method is Simple and best approach. For me it works with field array on rearrange.

Comment: what is the `watch`  method? where it come from?

Comment: it comes from methos, from useForm. 
`const { control, handleSubmit, watch } = methods;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from my codebase. In my case, I simply added a ternary operator to MUI's value prop. My previous code `value={value}` became `value={value ? value : ""}` and it sufficed to force MUI to rerender on each `value` change. I'm not fully certain on why this works, but if anyone knows, I would love to be enlightened.

```
 <Controller
      control={props.control}
      name={props.name}
      render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            value={value ? value : ""}
            type="text"
            label={props.label}
            {...props.register(props.name)}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
              onChange(e);
              if (props.onAfterChange) {
                props.onAfterChange(e);
              }
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it seems my problem was not related to react hook forms. the underlying component didn't re-render when the value was null. this answer solved my problem.